# Adding Event Listeners Fluently

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have difficulties adding event listeners to elements on my html documents.
What am I missing?

I always making mistakes.

I want to understand it at all and use it fluently.

For example, my new trial; this even a code from a similar question, I have just changed first event to "click". when I don't say anything about the element for which add the listener it works but on the clicks on entire body.

But I see following errors on Safari on my mac:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'formslink.addEventListener')
    global code (entr1.html, line 21)
```

Code for this is below:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
<script>
    function entranceForms()
    {
        var forms =  document.getElementById('entranceforms');

        if (forms.style.display === null || forms.style.display == 'none')
        {
            forms.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            forms.style.display = 'none';

        }
    }
    var formslink=document.getElementById('formslink');
    formslink.addEventListener('click', entranceForms, false);
    var formscancel=document.getElementById('formscancel');
    formscancel.addEventListener('click', entranceForms, false);
    </script>

    <body>
    <p id="formslink">entrance</p>

    <DIV ID='entranceforms' STYLE='display: none; width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 600px; z-index:1;
           background-color:white; opacity:1.0' >
            <P ID='formscancel'> Cancel </P> </DIV>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Put the `<script>` from `<head>` to (before) `<body>` tag.

Comment: it is still saying the same thing.

Comment: You are trying to access elements before they exist. Putting your `<script>`  element as the last child of `body` should fix that; otherwise, wrap the whole stuff into a function that gets executed when the `load` (or `DOMReady`) event has occurred.

Comment: i can't see anything to mark this solved or you as answerer.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element to add the method.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pgCqxCQ8MGeiahymcCpg?p=info

```
var elem = document.getElementById('entrancelink');
elem.addEventListener('click', entranceForms, false);
```

Comment: but I did have it. although it works now by putting script as a child of the body at the and of all html as @CBroe said.